# One or more properties contains invalid values When Call create user in office365

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

The api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` always return

```
One or more properties contains invalid values
```

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Header:

```
Authorization:Bearer xxxx
Content-Type:application/json
```

Body:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "lh lh",
    "mailNickname": "lhzc226",
    "userPrincipalName": "lhzc226@lhzc.cn",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "password": "@MvYE8177"
    }
}
```

return:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "One or more properties contains invalid values.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "e54a9d33-e9ec-4e9a-a867-2fc87d5ba807",
            "date": "2019-06-28T09:59:43"
        }
    }
}
```

Other APIs are available for calling. Currently, only the create user will report this error. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get found the key point. The domain **lhzc.cn** is not primary domain, set it to primary domain, and the api will not report an error